Autocorrelation of the lognormal Black-Scholes process
The Black-Scholes model with constant volatility $\sigma$ and interest rate $r$ is defined as
$$
dS_t/S_t=rdt+\sigma dW_t
$$
I derived the autocorrelation of the spot process $S_t$ for future times $0<t_1<t_2$ as follows:
$$
\text{Corr}(S_{t_1},S_{t_2})=\sqrt{\frac{e^{\sigma^2 t_1}-1}{e^{\sigma^2t_2}-1}}\quad\tag1
$$
It has the right limits (vanishes for $t_1=0$, equals to one for $t_2\to t_1+$, and is positive and smaller than one), but I am still somewhat puzzled that I have not found this formula anywhere in the internet.
Can someone please confirm that (1) is correct? Maybe also send some links where this is calculated?

thank you, good to know! I have Mathematica actually, but it didn't even cross my mind to check... shame on me
